# How do I get the author with the most submissions on a reddit crawl?

Tags: python, pandas

We're using pushshift and I've gathered the results already in:
[table of results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c7jTz.png)

```
rbreadit = pd.read_csv('rbreadit.csv', delimiter = ',')
rbreadit.count()
```

Since I'm trying to get the author with the most submissions, am I supposed to use `groupby` to first group the titles by author and then..?

```
mostposts = df.groupby("author")["title"].count()
mostposts.head()
```

Would appreciate any hint!

Comment: Can you provide some example data? It's difficulty to answer without knowing the structure of the DataFrame. At first glance ```df.groupby("author")["title"].count()``` looks weird. Maybe try  ```df["title"].groupby("author").count()```

Comment: @moritz sorry but how do i do that? since i just took data from r/breadit through pushshift. or, do you mean i can show the table of collected data itself?

Comment: Print your dataframe and copy paste the result. And if possible provide a way we can get the original data.